# Can I look up a string key in a hashmap with convenient syntax?

Tags: clojure

Being able to access key of `(def my-hashmap {:one 1})` with `(:one my-hashmap)` is very convenient. Sometimes I have hashmaps that have string values.

I want to be able to be able to access `(def my-hashmap {"one" 1})` with syntax like `("one" my-hashmap)`. Obviously, I can't. My options are either use `(get my-hashmap "one")` or to transform the hashmap so it has symbols for keys. I'd rather not, as I'll be passing the object to other functions which might expect it to be in the original format.

What is the shortest way I can look up a string key? Is `get` the only way or is there some magic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `map` can be used as a function

```
(my-hashmap "one")
```

Comment: Note that if my-hashmap is nil you will get a NullPointerException, `get` will return nil

Answer (score 1):

If you're already passing the map as a function parameter or `let`-bound variable, you can also do destructuring of a map with string keys using the `:strs` keyword:

```
(let [{:strs [a]} {"a" 1, "b" 2}]
  a)
; => 1
```